# .Net Framework underline implementation

Tags: .net, winapi, implementation, system-calls

I wish to know how is the .Net framework implemented behind the curtains.

In the WinApi, a call to WriteFile (kernel32.DLL) will end up calling NtWriteFile (ntdll.dll) that in turn will call KiSystemService that will invoke the system call that handles writing files.

I wish to understand how is the process done when calling File.Write() in the .Net Framework.

Does the .Net Framework eventually calls WriteFile in kernel32 ?

Or does it skips over the WinApi and goes straight to work by invoking the system service by calling KiSystemService ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no File.Write in the File class so I assume you are talking about File.WriteAllBytes and it calls the Win32 `WriteFile` as I can understand from the source code of the Framework.

The File class creates a FileStream that internally ends to use the private method `WriteFileNative`...

This method after some checking on the parameters passed and on the async call state use the following code

```
fixed (byte* numRef = bytes)
{
    if (this._isAsync)
    {
        num2 = Win32Native.WriteFile(handle, numRef + offset, count, IntPtr.Zero, overlapped);
    }
    else
    {
        num2 = Win32Native.WriteFile(handle, numRef + offset, count, out numBytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to presume that the .Net Framework will always go through the WinApi ? That the flow will always be .Net Framework => Windows Api => Native Api ?

Comment: Well the Framework is huge, and so, no I can't say that it is safe. Besides, the whole point to have a framework is to not worry for these details, however this link points to the [Framework sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx). You could check on them when you need to know